# How to make animated gif from non consecutive images?

Tags: video, image-processing, imagemagick, animated-gif

I have  [a series of images](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Discrete_dynamic_in_case_of_complex_quadratic_polynomial.gif) numbered from 0 to 1200. I want to create animated image ( gif ). I do not want to use all images [0,1200] so I have removed some images : [11,14], [16,19]. Now series has a "holes" but I still want to show them in ascending order ( from smallest=  0 to highest = 1200). If I use :

```
  convert -resize 800x600 -delay 50  -loop 0 %d.gif[0-1200] a.gif
```

then order is not good. 
How should I do it ?

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unix command [sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) is your friend for this.

```
convert `ls *.gif | sort -n` -resize 800x600 -delay 50  -loop 0 a.gif
```

> I do not want to use all images

That's very unique to you, and should be clarified with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is it. Thx. I have edited my question and added a link to page where is an image ( manually build) and code.